# Is Akka's routers similar to Go's select?

Tags: go, concurrency, akka, message-passing

I read that Akka library has something called "Routers" which routes messages to their routees (who will receive the messages). Is this similar to selective communication in Go which uses the select statement?

Comment: In general, you can typically implement *any* concurrency abstraction from one concurrency model using the concurrency abstractions of some other general concurrency model. So, the question is: what do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: Please see my comment to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47201862/720999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar in abstract terms and general understanding but very different if you compare with Akka router.

As you are trying to compare a language feature with a framework feature here is an explantation.

Go uses select over channels and this feature is a basic building block which you can use to extend routing and add many features which Akka has. Try looking into some fantastic GitHub libraries.

https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#routers

Akka itself is huge and very well written. Akka router has many other options which includes routing strategy and remote routing as well.

go-select is a language feature which makes it easier to implement routing feature if you compare with other languages (readers-no language war please!)

Thanks